# How to download file from url in Ionic 5 without using FileTransfer

Tags: typescript, file, ionic-framework, ionic-native

I'm currently developing Ionic app now and stuck at file download part. I saw many posts that `FileTransfer` cordova library is now deprecated in favor of XHR request.

Even though I saw many posts that the library is deprecated, I can't find any sample code (for downloading file from URL).

Could anyone please suggest me good way to download file from url without using `FileTransfer` plugin?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Downloading files from another server may cause annoying **CORS** error which is mostly beyond our control. The safest way is to bypass the Webview and download the file natively. You may use **Native HTTP** plugin

Use in Ionic 4 or above will look like:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { HTTP } from '@ionic-native/http/ngx';
import { File } from '@ionic-native/file/ngx';
        
@Component({
   selector: 'app-home',
   templateUrl: './you-file.html',
   styleUrls: ['./your-file.scss'],
})

export class HomePage {
    constructor(private nativeHTTP: HTTP, private file: File) {}
        
     private downloadFileAndStore() {
        //
        const filePath = this.file.dataDirectory + fileName; 
                         // for iOS use this.file.documentsDirectory
        
        this.nativeHTTP.downloadFile('your-url', {}, {}, filePath).then(response => {
           // prints 200
           console.log('success block...', response);
        }).catch(err => {
            // prints 403
            console.log('error block ... ', err.status);
            // prints Permission denied
            console.log('error block ... ', err.error);
        })
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: This works like a charm for native devices, but is there any workaround in this for browser.

Comment: this doesn't work for me. No errors, just nothing is happening

Comment: @YevheniiBahmutskyi where are you testing? the code is for native devices and you can not test this using your browser. Have you tried testing on your device in debug mode and printing console logs on the terminal/command window?

Comment: @ArupBhattacharya thank you for solution. I use your function on ios device and I have this issue : " 2021-09-17 11:18:41.526015+0100 F[1617:318799] error block ... 403 2021-09-17 11:18:41.526434+0100 F[1617:318799] error block ... There was an error downloading the file"

Answer (score 1):

You can just open the url with `window`. But this will open a browser and
download the file there. It will do the trick although it is not pretty:

your.page.ts:

```js
function download(url){
  window.open(url, "_blank");
}
```

your.html:

```html
<a href="javascript:void(0)" (click)="download(yourUrl)">Your file name</>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the solution I used for react, downloading files MP4 and save in the cache  or documents, Filesystem is for capacitor.

```
const bob = await fetch(url).then((x) => x.blob());
       const base64 = await convertBlobToBase64(bob);

    const resultSaveFile = await Filesystem.writeFile({
        data: base64,
        path: 'video-edit.mp4',
        directory: directory || Directory.Cache,
        recursive: true,
      });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use simply `HttpClient` class (`@angular/common/http`) as follow:

```js
const downloadPath = (
   this.platform.is('android')
) ? this.file.externalDataDirectory : this.file.documentsDirectory;


let vm = this;

/** HttpClient - @angular/common/http */
this.http.get(
   uri, 
   {
      responseType: 'blob', 
      headers: {
         'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + yourTokenIfYouNeed,
      }
   }
).subscribe((fileBlob: Blob) => {
   /** File - @ionic-native/file/ngx */
   vm.file.writeFile(downloadPath, "YourFileName.pdf", fileBlob, {replace: true});
});
```

Imports you will need:

```js
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { File } from '@ionic-native/file/ngx';
```

Answer (score 0):

To be able to download and see files via ionic-native `File` I had to add additional settings inside Xcode:

*confing.xml*

```
<preference name="iosPersistentFileLocation" value="Library" />
```

*info.plist*

```
<key>UIFileSharingEnabled</key> <true/>
<key>LSSupportsOpeningDocumentsInPlace</key> <true/>
```

Download path should be `File.documentsDirectory`

Answer (score -1):

You can Achieve this in the following steps :

**Step 1**: A download function to download from URL

```
downloadFile(path: string, body: Object = {}): Observable<any> {
  let headers = {} // add authentication headers and other headers as per your requirement
  return this.http.post/get( 
    `${path}`, body, { headers: headers, withCredentials: true }
  )
  .catch((err) =>console.log(err))
  .map((res:Response) => res)
  .finally( () => { });
}
```

**Step 2**: Use the download function to convert it into an appropriate Blob.

```
this.downloadFile(`url`, postData).subscribe(
 res => {
   let options = { type: ‘filetype’ };
   let filename = ‘filename.type’;
   Util.createAndDownloadBlobFile(res._body, options, filename);
 },
 err => {
   // show the error
 }
);
```

**Step 3**: Save the Blob Data on Device using following plugin https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file

Comment: I'm getting CORS error when I send get request to server for files. Do I have to manage cors in backend side?

Comment: Ok, Btw Can you please share full source code for reference. And also I think we can use `reponsetype`: `blob` in get request.

Comment: This is my import and it throws the error ```import { Observable } from 'rxjs';```. Please show the import of Observable.  Beacuse here it shows can't use .catch on Observable.

Comment: this code is not valid and also badly written